# Add a user-role as custom meta data to WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders, user-roles

In WooCommerce I am wondering if it's possible to save the user role as a custom field to the order *(custom meta data)* using `user_role` meta key, like in this screenshot:

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will add the user roles as custom order meta data:

```
// Add the user roles as order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_user_roles_to_order_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function add_user_roles_to_order_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    if( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
        $user = $order->get_user();
        $user_role = reset($user->roles)

        $order->update_meta_data( 'user_role', $user_role );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

To get the user role from the `WC_Order` Object `$order` variable you will use:

```
$user_role = $order->get_meta('user_role');
```

Or from the order Id `$order_id` variable:

```
$user_role = get_post_meta($order_id, 'user_role', true);
```